# Upload Video using Delphi RestRequest on Vimeo does not work in Linux (same code works in Windows)

Tags: linux, rest, delphi, mime-types, vimeo-api

I am using TRestRequest to upload videos on Vimeo. It works very well in a Windows application.
The same Delphi project is deployed to Linux Ubuntu 18.04. The upload does not work in Linux. The response to the Request is that zero bytes was sent.

Here is the basic code for the request:

```
var
  tamanhoenvio: real;
  LBuffer: TBytes;
  NomeCompleto: string;
  MemoryStream1: tMemoryStream;
  byteslidos: integer;
  LInput: TFileStream;
begin
  NomeCompleto:= '/srv/conteudo/Pasta_001/video.mp4';
  LInput:= TFileStream.Create(NomeCompleto, fmOpenRead);
  tamanhoenvio:= LInput.Size; 
  SetLength(LBuffer, trunc(tamanhoenvio));
  byteslidos:= LInput.Read(Pointer(LBuffer)^, trunc(tamanhoenvio));
  MemoryStream1 := TMemoryStream.Create; 
  MemoryStream1.Write(LBuffer, byteslidos);
  MemoryStream1.Position:= 0;   
  with RESTRequestUpload do
  begin
    { I have tried to use a parameter body created in design mode and used
    // Params.ParameterByName('body').SetStream(MemoryStream1);
      but the result is the same }

    AddBody(MemoryStream1,ctVIDEO_MP4);
    Params.ParameterByName('upload-offset').Value:= floattostr(Posicao);
    Execute;
  end;
  // the original code is larger with try-finally block with free and other 
     statements
end;
```

The upload process in Vimeo starts with the video creation, followed by the upload itself using TUS. I have success in Windows from the video creation until completing the upload. In Linux, the video is created on Vimeo platform, but any byte can't be sent.

Is there anything that I have to change in my code to adapt to running in Linux?

Comment: Can you show the code where you load the file to memory stream!? It's likely that there is some very simple error. Your provided code fragment is not helpful for us.

Comment: Hi, @DelphiCoder! I put more lines according to my code to show how I load the file to the memory stream.

Comment: Why isn't tamanhoenvio an integer? Why not load the TMemoryStream from the file?